# Image variable in imread()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to subtract the background of image and then draw contours.
I'm using the `removebg` API to subtract the background, and I want to take the image result and draw contours on it.

Removing the background:

```
rmbg = RemoveBg("MY_KEY_API", "error.log")
img_no_bg = rmbg.remove_background_from_img_file("images/imagetest.png")
```

I want to convert the result `imagetest_no-bg.png` to grayscale, but I can't use `img_no_bg` as the attribute for the function `imread()`.

```
image = cv2.imread(img_no_bg)
gray = gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_no_bg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: 1) What does RemoveBg's `remove_background_from_img_file()` method return?
2) `imread()` method from OCV takes as an argument a path to the file to be read. You'd rather want to convert the output from the bcg remove api to the object that can be processed in OCV library

Comment: @Croolman: the method remove_background_from_img_file() returns the image (imagetest.png) with no background called imagetest_no-bg.png 
how can i take that output and read it in order to apply some effects like grayscale. because my objective after, is to do this for all images in a folder.

Comment: Then it does not retur nad path, `imread()` is not usable here, the image is already loaded. Still dont know what type the method from `RemoveBg` returns. Try excluding the imread and put the `img_no_bg` directly to the `cvtColor`. Just guessing here though.

Comment: I already tried to put` img_no_bg` in the `cvtColor`, but it doesn't work.
what `RemoveBg` does is: take a picture X.png and then remove it's background and save it under a new name that is `X_no_bg.png`, i want to take the `X_no_bg.png` and convert it to grayscale.

Comment: Ok, so it saves it again. Well then just take (name of) whatever file you're opening, and add `_no_bg.png` that name pass to `imread()`

Comment: Yeah, i already tested it in the first place and it works fine, but i need this one for my next step which provides me to takeimages from folder...

Comment: an example image with a piece of running code would be perfect to work with and be able to help you.